# How to add a column with unique row_id for a PySpark dataframe that start the row_id from the max(row_id) +1 from previous code run

Tags: python, pyspark

I have used the code below to create a new column with unique row_id, but everytime I run the code, the row_id is starting from 0. I want the row_id to start from the highest row_id from the previous code run.

Please help!

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
new_raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1. `monotonically_increasing_id` doesn't work that way, it will generate a 64-bit digit starting from 0 in every run and in an increasing order but if your dataframe has more than one partition (`raw_df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`) then it will add the hashid of the partition to it. refer [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id).
2. If you need the number to be added across from the previous run then save it as an `offset` variable and add to it, something like:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
# Have added 1 just in case you need the ids from 1 onwards and not zero
new_raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id() + 1 + offset)
```

Also, if you are looking for is a surrogate-id generation mechanism then you can use `df.rdd.zipWithIndex` + `offset` but you will still have to store the offset from the previous `spark-submit` somewhere.